# Change default character set on MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to connect to my MYSQL database using a `utf8mb4` charset (Note the global settings for the database charset is already utf8mb4).

I can do this quite easily using the CLI like so:

```
mysql -h myhostname -u myuser -p --default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

When I do the following query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
```

I get the correct output as expected:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

However, when I connect to my MySQL database using **MySQL Workbench**, and perform the same query I get the following:

```
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8               |
| character_set_connection | utf8               |
| character_set_database   | latin1             |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8               |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci    |
| collation_database       | latin1_swedish_ci  |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

The issue here is that I am struggling to change the `default-character-set` in MySQL Workbench GUI. I tried appending the following:

```
default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

in Manage Server Connections > Connection > Advanced > Others section,

but does not seem to have any affect.

How can I change the default character set on the MySQL Workbench GUI.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? Thanks!

Comment: No. Fortunately, it doesn't seem to be causing much issues. I hope there is a fix though.

Comment: any idea on mac?

Answer (score 12):

AFAIK you have to execute this command each time you start a new Workbench session:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
```

**UPDATE**

The following is useful if you need to use Workbench to do exports: (I haven't found a similar way to cause all it's connections to default to utf8mb4)

The default charset that is used is to export data is utf8. To support full Unicode though we need utf8mb4. To achieve this it's possible to modify Workbench to use utf8mb4 manually.

- Go to C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules
  open this file wb_admin_export.py.
- On a Mac Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/Resources/plugins/wb_admin_export.py
- Create a backup copy
- Replace all occurrences "default-character-set":"utf8" with "default-character-set":"utf8mb4".
- Save the file.
- Restart Workbench.

The next time you run the export you will see in the log results like this:

Running: mysqldump.exe --defaults-file="c:\users\jonathan\appdata\local\temp\tmpidlh7a.cnf" --host=localhost --protocol=tcp --user=root --allow-keywords=TRUE --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8mb4 --routines --skip-triggers "databasename"

Comment: This is so frustrating :/ but thank you for confirming it

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL Workbench (8.0), you can click the *Administration* tab, select *Options File* under **Instance**, scroll to the *International* section and you'll find *character-set-server* and *collation-server*, which you can set to your desired charset and collation. Click the **Apply** button to save the changes.

This will set the values in /etc/mysql/my.cnf, or wherever your config file is.